# How can read system env in pkg-config pc file

Tags: pkg-config

I want to read system env USER when def .pc like this.
But it do not work. Can I read system env In .pc ？Thanks

```
prefix=/home/${USER}/depend/x264.148
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: x264
Description: H264 encode
Version: 148
Libs: -L${libdir} -lx264 
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prefix=~/depend/x264.148
```

It works